# Reusing, and Editing child view's properties of Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to mimic the app list page of Google's Play Store.
to do that, I have made a Relative view for each app box which contains icon, title, developer, etc...

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="205px"
            android:layout_height="310px"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px" 
            android:layout_margin="4px">

            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/icon1"
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:text="@string/t1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="20px" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/title1"
                android:text="@string/company"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="15px" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to put 72 different app boxes in a big scroll view but that requires thousands of lines..
I know I can reuse custom view with  but I have know idea how to change the properties of sub-level view(child view). (like Image src of the code above.)

Is there anyway to shorten the line or reuse the custom view?
Or.. Is there a easier way to make 72 different app boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a `GridView` or `ListView`, and an `ArrayAdapter` inflated with the above layout. It's rather hard to help you any further until you investigate this route.

[GridView Information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

[ListView Information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

[Adapter Information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)